# zsh ignores HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS

Tags: linux, zsh

I am trying to configure my Z shell to not show duplicate history entries with 'setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS'.

```
HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS
When searching for history entries in the line editor, do not display duplicates of a line previously found, even if the duplicates are not contiguous.
```

However, it does not work in the expected way. When I have this history:

```
    1  history
    2  cd /bin
    3  cd /bin
    4  cd /bin
```

I expect to press UP twice (which is set to 'up-line-or-history') and get 'history' in my prompt. However instead I get 'cd /bin'. If I press UP four times it goes to 'history' command, which is basically the default behaviour without HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS set.

I know that I could use other options that would prevent duplicate commands from getting saved in the first place (such as HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS), but that is not the behaviour that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS`

> When **s̲e̲a̲r̲c̲h̲i̲n̲g̲** for history entries in the line editor, do not display duplicates of a line previously found, even if the duplicates are not contiguous.

I think it works as designed and `setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS` should not affect the results when you just press up arrow. It affects on search results displayed then you press `Ctrl-r`. Suppose you have the following history:

```
mvn clean package
mvn clean package
mvn clean package -DSkipTests
mvn clean package
```

Now if you press `Ctrl-r` and type `mvn` you will get `mvn clean package` suggestion. When you press `Ctrl-r` again, you will get `mvn clean package -DSkipTests`. Pressing `Ctrl-r` for the 3rd time will not lead to a new suggestion, because duplicates are not allowed by `HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS`. Without `HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS` the shell would show you `mvn clean package` again.